# How does changing to a new host / changing IP address affect SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search, web-hosting

I am looking to change hosts (transfer fron a dedicated cloud to a dedicated cloud), but I'm worried my high traffic site will lose a lot of SEO authority due to changing the IP address of the the server? Is there any way to keep same IP address but change hosts? What recommendations to minimize the impact on SEO when changing hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: https://www.woorank.com/en/blog/how-will-changing-ip-address-impact-seo (I have no affiliation, I just did a quick search).

> Websites also have IP addresses, assigned by the server on which they
> are stored. If you move your website to a new server (also known as a
> hosting service) the IP address of your site will change. This puts
> many people off making the move because they fear that such a drastic
> change will have a huge impact on their website's SEO. All that hard
> work optimizing their website undone in one fell swoop.
>
> But are these concerns legitimate or is this another myth borne from
> Google's notorious secrecy? Well, you'll be pleased to hear that for
> the most part there's little to worry about. According to our
> research, the SEO impact of changing IP addresses is minimal.